# Correct way to iterate through and populate a column in excel with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, iteration

Okay I need some help.  This was supposed to iterate through the 35,021 rows of an excel spreadsheet and populate the column drg_id from the DRG.xlsx into a cvs sheet
.  Instead it only populated just the original 7 items into 7 of the 35,021 rows in a new column.  What am I doing wrong?

```
drg = pd.read_excel('C:/Cardiac DRG.xlsx', sheet_name=0, index_col=0)
list_A = drg['DRG'].tolist()
print(list_A)
series_A = pd.Series(list_A)
##Add in  the DRG to the next empty column
##df['DRG'] = series_A.values
drg_list = []
drgs = list_A 
##series_A #unique names in user_id column
drg_id_col = list(drg['DRG']) #assign column to list
def rand_reviewer(list_of_drgs):#function to generate rand user
    return list_of_drgs[random.randint(0,35021)]
for i in range(35021, len(drgs)): #iterate over list 
    drg_list.append(rand_reviewer(drgs))
    while drg_id_col[i] == drg_list[i]: #generate random user until id's don't match
        drg_list[i] = rand_reviewer(drgs)
series_B = pd.Series(drg_id_col)
df3['drg_id'] = series_B  ##add new column to df
```

Comment: `for i in range(35021,len(drgs)):` -- what do you believe that is doing?

Comment: I thought it was supposed to iterate through 35201 rows for that column, populating it with one of the values from the other list.

Comment: No.  That creates a range starting with 35021 an ending just before `len(drgs)`.  Is `len(drgs)` supposed to be 35021?    Perhaps you meant `range(len(drgs))`, or even `enumerate(drgs)`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts so do I have the iteration in the wrong place?  I am trying to pull 7 unique codes from an excel workbook and populate 35021 rows in a new column in csv.

Comment: I went back and took out the 35021 in the for i in range(35021, len(drgs)):  and it gave an error of out of range.

Comment: We don't really have enough information.  What does `print(drg.shape)` say?

Comment: drg has two columns; DRGNAME, DRG with 7 rows.  That's it.

Comment: drgs just has the drg column which is List_A - the 7 drgs.

Comment: Well, then, how on earth do you expect to refer to the 35,020th row?

Comment: I am trying to understand how it should work.  Berating me doesn't help.  If you can help by explaining what I am doing wrong- that would help.

Comment: Your description is contradictory.  What's in the spreadsheet?  Is it 35,000 rows, or is it 7 rows?  If it has 35,000 rows, then why does `drg` only have 7 rows?  What are you expecting in your output?

Comment: Tim in the csv file it has 35021 rows-this is the file we are appending a new column to.  In the other, excel workbook, is 7 rows- these are the rows we are grabbing and appending randomly to the csv file.

Comment: Where is "the other"?  I only see one `read_excel` here.  `drg` and `list_A` and `series_A` and `drgs` and `drg_id_col` all come from the `read_excel`.

Comment: df3['drg_id'] = series_B ##add new column to df then I write to csv from df3.  So I understand I want to pull from one excel spreadsheet and append a column to another csv file (excel).  SO what am I doing wrong?  I have append in the code.

Comment: So, `drg` (and friends) has 7 rows, and `df3` (which you didn't show us) has 35,000 rows, and your goal is to add a column to `df3` that contains randomly selected entries from `drg['DRG']`?  If so, that's only a couple lines of code.

Comment: No. drg has 7 rows, column with name, colum with drg number.  The other csv file has 35021 rows- which is what we are appending the drg to, making a new column in it. I am glad you are saying it is only a couple of lines of code.  But you haven't offered anything to help but questions?  Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

This extracts the DRG column from `drg`, and populates a new column in `df3` with random selections from that column.  That seems to be what your code was trying to do.

```
drg = pd.read_excel('C:/Cardiac DRG.xlsx', sheet_name=0, index_col=0)
list_A = drg['DRG'].tolist()
df3['drg_id'] = random.choices(list_A, k=len(df3.index))
```

Comment: I hadn't come across random.choices.  So I don't have to iterate through the 35,000 rows?

Comment: Okay I am getting an error for this - list object has no attribute 'to_csv'   df = pd.read_csv('cardio_train_onlycardio.csv')
df3 = df
drg = pd.read_excel('/Cardiac DRG.xlsx', sheet_name=0, index_col=0)
list_A = drg['DRG'].tolist()
df3 = random.choices(list_A, k=len(df.index))
df3.to_csv (('cardio_train_drgadded_test1.csv'))
df3.shape

Comment: That's not what I wrote.  You want `random.choices` to go to one COLUMN of `df3`.  Your code replaces the entire dataframe.

Comment: Huh.  But it is not going over to df and inserting (appending) the df3 column that is needed in the df excel spreadsheet where I need it.  :-)

Comment: If you want it in `df`, then insert it into `df`.  Your sample code above was shoving it into `df3`.  That leaves `df` alone.

Comment: Are you saying to change this df3 = random.choices(list_A, k=len(df.index) to df = random.choices(list_A, k=len(df3.index)?  I have never had anyone help like this- its very frustrating.

Comment: NO, that's not what I wrote!!!  I wrote `df3['drg_id'] = random.choices(...)`.  Note the column name after `df3`.  That's what makes it add a new column.  What you're doing replaces the whole dataframe.

Comment: Thank you I understand that part.  I didn't understand shoving it into df.  I do that now with the original code at the top, it just only fills the 7 rows with a new column, so?

Comment: If `df` has 35,000 rows, then `df['drg_id'] = random.choices(list_A, k=len(df.index))` will fill that column in all 35,000 rows.  If you're inserting it into a dataframe with 7 rows, it will only fill 7 rows.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense now.  Thank you!